# React-native Android : unable to generate signed APK : "no such scale"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to publish my first Android / React Native app.

I'm following "Sign your app" Google page (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) and "Generating Signed APK" React Native page (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) and I can't generate the APK correctly.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank You.

I have a weird error message "no such scale" when trying to generate the signed APK. The keystore file is away of the project so signing informations aren't in the app projet.

I tried

- > rm -rf node_modules && yarn install
- > Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

APK generation

```
$./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace --info

[...]

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' (up-to-date check took 0.839 secs) due to:
  Task has failed previously.
Starting process 'command 'node''. Working directory: MyApp Command: node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
Successfully started process 'command 'node''
Scanning folders for symlinks in MyApp/node_modules (21ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in MyApp/node_modules (24ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output

no such scale

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 2 mins 1.325 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractExecTask.exec(AbstractExecTask.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 27 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s
50 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 48 up-to-date
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Keys.repo=/<absolute_path_away_project>/Android_certificates/
```

keystores/release.keystore.properties

```
keyAlias='SigningKeyAlias'
keyPassword='<password_string>'
storeFile='<store_filename'
storePassword='<password_store'
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
]


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// release.keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = file("keystores/release.keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

def projectPropsFile = file(project.property("Keys.repo") + keystoreProperties['storeFile'])

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile projectPropsFile
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification-ce')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the reason was I had invalid (?) dpi specifiers in image file names.

My device dpi is 400, so I had files like `myimage@2.5x.png`. The debug version built just fine but not the release. As soon as I changed 2.5 to 2 the release version got built.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had an image who was ended with "2.5x" too. Thank you guy ! I'm preparing a pull request to react-native to have a console.warn with the filename next time.

Answer (score 1):

The `dpi`s must be one of :
[image]

As it appears here : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.
In case there is an invalid dpi (even only one) the images are not compiled.